# Google Geocode format address contains hexadecimal characters

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder

I am using `google geocode API` and for certain addresses I am seeing hexadecimal values in the formatted_address field.

Result from Google geocode API:

```
formatted_address" : "[Geocode \"8776\" (0xccbaa26b30dcc864), Feature (TYPE_ESTABLISHMENT_POI) \"Drum Oil & Propane Co\" [en LP] (0xfcffc173b794989a)
```

Can someone help me understand what could be the reason for the same.

Comment: That's odd. What is your input string?

Comment: Hi Ervin,             Below is the input string that I have used.                https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=57ARMSTRONGRD+PLYMOUTH+MA+02360&key=             Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Google bug.

I tried the same with geocoder:

https://geocoder.ca/57ARMSTRONGRD+PLYMOUTH+MA+02360?geoit=xml

And got:

```html
{
  "standard": {
    "staddress": "Armstrong Rd",
    "stnumber": "57",
    "prov": "MA",
    "city": "Plymouth",
    "postal": "02360-4806",
    "confidence": "1"
  },
  "longt": "-70.695522",
  "TimeZone": "America\/New_York",
  "AreaCode": "508,774",
  "latt": "41.956622"
}
```

```
 <geodata>
 <latt>41.956622</latt>
 <longt>-70.695522</longt>
 <AreaCode>508,774</AreaCode>
 <TimeZone>America/New_York</TimeZone>
 <standard>
 <stnumber>57</stnumber>
 <staddress>Armstrong Rd</staddress>
 <city>Plymouth</city>
 <prov>MA</prov>
 <postal>02360-4806</postal>
 <confidence>1</confidence>
 </standard>
 </geodata>
```

Here is the same result in json:

https://geocoder.ca/57ARMSTRONGRD+PLYMOUTH+MA+02360?geoit=xml&json=1

```
{
"standard": {
"staddress": "Armstrong Rd",
"stnumber": "57",
"prov": "MA",
"city": "Plymouth",
"postal": "02360-4806",
"confidence": "1"
 },
 "longt": "-70.695522",
 "TimeZone": "America\/New_York",
 "AreaCode": "508,774",
 "latt": "41.956622"
 }
```

: 
https://geocoder.ca/57ARMSTRONGRD+PLYMOUTH+MA+02360

Comment: Thank you Ervin for your response. It answered my question.